# How to reduce the file upload time?

Tags: php, file-upload, bandwidth, php-ini

I need to upload large size video files. I've set the maximum file upload preferences. Ive set the following preferences:

```
memory_limit        :150M
upload_max_filesize :120M
post_max_size       :120M  
max_execution_time  :300s 
max_input_time      :300s
```

> It works but for larger video files takes too long. For 12M it takes 5mns, for 50M it may
>   take nearly 30mns. Is there any way to reduce the file upload  time.
>
> After Executing I get this warning message:
>    "PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 12959997 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Find out what your bottleneck is and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: What maximum upload speeds are you getting from your present location? [Find out here](http://www.speedtest.net/) - it might be that you are maxing out your local net connection, and it simply won't go any faster.

Answer (score 2):

File upload time is dependant on a number of factors including your upload speed, the servers download speed.I suspect the limiting factor here is your upload speed. Try uploading to somewhere else, see if the upload is any faster. Remember to choose a server in and around the same location as your current one for a more equal comparison.

If the download speeds are pretty similar then the "problem" lies with your Internet connection. If not, it's something server side.

Comment: I get this "PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 15773026 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0" and the connection speed is 100Mbps